# How to read the excels 'Student Name' column data using xlrd?

Tags: python, xlrd

How to read the **excels** 'Student Name' **column** data using ***xlrd***?

Please find the below image for the reference :

[image]

Comment: Can you show any attempts you made in order to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd
book=xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xlsx')
print book.nsheets
print book.sheet_names()
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(1)
sheet.col_values(col_num) #This line reads the column data. I guess you know how to load the sheet and all.
```